# Error: ETextLayoutException with message point not in layout?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have 6 expanders components inside a multiview component and when compiling they do not open the expanders, in windows I get the error: point not in layout and in delphi ETextLayoutException with message point not in layout error. Inside the expander, I have a memo and a button inside each expander. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to post your layout here. Also, it might be helpful to include Delphi in the subject so people know without reading the entire text and tags what the error relates to. Also layout is misspelled 'layaout' which might hurt other people searching for the same error.

Comment: I do not have a reputation for uploading images that would allow me to better understand the problem ...

Comment: You should copy the code, not upload an image.